# Problem with uploading files on root linux server

Tags: php, apache, redhat, centos5, file-ownership

I have a plesk panel and root dedicated server on 1and1. I'm using custom programed php script to upload the files and create the folders to server. I have the upload folder named upload_data_folder with the 777 permission.

The scenario is the following:
I want to create folder in my **upload_data_folder** and than upload files in that newly crated folder. I'm doing this over php script so every file or folder that I create has apache user and the group as the owner.

1. I'm successfully crate the folder in my **upload_data_folder** and that folder is owned by apache, has apache as a group and has 777 premission. Then When I try to upload some files to that newly created folder It can't.

I think the problem is with some owner permission but if anyone has some idea what this can be I would be very grateful

Comment: If you have 777 on the dir then it should work. Do you get some kind of error message? I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Your permissions seems fine, it sounds like you're using some script you found somewhere.  Perhaps it sucks.  Sounds like you'll need to debug this script, or write your own.  Start here: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: I agree with Martin on this one - have you looked in the apache log files or the php log files? Usually if an error occurs it'll be logged there. You might also run a local copy of apache/php with all the debug variables on to test your scripts first - this is what I do (albeit with Python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my custom made script. huuu I solved the problem. The php safe mode was turned on. After I turned it off everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

By default apache document root is /var/www/html/. If plesk is installed document root will have a path like:/var/www/httpdocs for non-secure sites. Thus secure sites are stored in /var/www/httpsdocs.